# Why Scrollspy is not loaded in react app?

Tags: reactjs, scrollspy

I have `npx create-react-app` project. It was working good on older system but not working in my new mac. Wonder why Scrollspy can not be loaded. Got following error on `npm start`

```
./src/components/MyComponent.js
Cannot find file: 'Scrollspy.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: 
'./node_modules/react-scrollspy/lib/scrollspy.js
```

In `MyComponent.js`, I have imported `Scrollspy` like:

```
import Scrollspy from 'react-scrollspy';
```

Comment: Have you installed dependencies by running `npm install` in your app directory?

Comment: Yea I did.... however after day it started work... not sure why.